# Problema para instalar o gcc no ubuntu

Tags: linux, gcc

Estou tentando instalar o GCC no ubuntu. Quando digito `sudo apt-get instal gcc`
pede uma senha, mas eu não consigo digitar a senha. Qual pode ser o problema?

Comment: A senha não aparece (nem as bolinhas ou "*") mas estás a escreve-la, é normal, digita a senha e carrega enter

Comment: mas quando eu tento digitar nao acontece nada, nem aparece ***

Comment: É normal Gabriela, tal como te disse no cometário acima... Lê o que te disse

Comment: No terminal linux não aparece nada quando digita a senha, mas está digitando sim.

Answer (score 3):

Por medidas de segurança, quando você executa o comando `sudo` no Linux, o Terminal pede que você digite sua senha sem *feedback* visual enquanto você digita. Mesmo que nenhum carácter apareça enquanto você digita sua senha, você está realmente digitando ela.

Digite a senha e pressione <kbd>Enter</kbd> para ver a magia acontecer.

Caso você se sinta desconfortável por isso, há maneiras de fazer com que apareça o `***`, mas seria por conta e risco do usuário. Veja [esse artigo](http://www.howtogeek.com/194010/how-to-make-password-asterisks-visible-in-the-terminal-window-in-linux/)<sup>(en)</sup> ensinado como fazer.